# Scrolling inside "swipeable area" is a little lagging?

Tags: flutter

Example: inside a swipeable tab menu(https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs), I added a Listview, and when I start dragging down the Listview, the screen not scrolling down until my finger move like "20 pixels".

But if a Listview is not inside a swipeable area, the screen start scrolling down after my finger moved like "5 pixels".

I'm not sure if I have explained clearly. I have tested 3rd party apps, and they result the same. Anyone know how to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),` in your ListView

Comment: Added but no changes. I'm testing using iOS device.